# Javascript array to Django many to many field

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django form with Area and Subarea. The subarea input is a ManytoManyField (not every area is a subarea but all subarea is an area), but I have to style it in the frontend, in a way that I can add and remove elements from a text input before I submit the form. I have already implemented a JavaScript function that collects all subareas in an array.
I would like to know how can I pass this array to Django, so it can go to the Subarea field and save it. Is there any possible way?

Django models.py:

```
class Area(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   is_subarea = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   Subarea = models.ManyToManyField('Area', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Django views.py:

```
class AddLanguageView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   model = Area
   template_name = 'language/add-language.html'
   form_class = LanguageForm

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       area = Area()
       area.name = request.POST.get('nome')
       area.subarea = request.POST.get('Subarea')
       area.save()

       return render(request, 'language/add-language.html')
```

```js
let sublanguageArray = [];
let i = 0;

const addSublanguage = () => {

  // Add to array
  const sublanguage = document.getElementById("sublanguage-input").value;
  sublanguageArray.push({
    name: sublanguage,
    id: i
  });
  
  // Screen Preview
  document.querySelector('#sublanguages').innerHTML += `
    <div>
      <div class="delete-sublanguage">
        <img src="/static/assets/delete.png" id-delete="${i}" onclick="deleteSublanguage(this)">
      </div>
      ${sublanguage}
    </div>
  `;

  i++

}
// Delete html preview and from array
const deleteSublanguage = (item) => {
  const block = item.parentElement.parentElement;
  block.parentNode.removeChild(block);
  sublanguageArray = sublanguageArray.filter(sub => sub.id !== +item.getAttribute('id-delete'));
};
```

```html
<form method="POST" class="add-language-form" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="language-title-box" >
                    <h2>Linguagem:</h2>
                    {{ form.name }}
                </div>
                <div class="subarea-box">
                    <h2>Sub-linguagem</h2>
                    <input type="text" id="sublanguage-input">
                    <button id="submit-sublanguage" onclick="addSublanguage()">ADD</button>
                    <div id="sublanguages"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="submit-lang-box" >
                    <input type="submit" value="ADD AREA" id="addLanguageButton" next="partials/base.html">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Please share the code that you wrote. Also please be more precise, about what help do you require

Comment: What's not working with the code that you've posted?

Comment: It’s working. I want to know how to pass the array to django forms as a manytomanyfield generates a select tag